# Warning: Rejected - All hosts are taken by other resources

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to setup `Nginx-ingress controller` to manage two paths on the same `hostname` in bare metal based cluster.

In the **app1** namespace i have below nginx resource:-

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app1-ingress
  namespace: app1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: web.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app1
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: app1-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

And in the **app2** namespace i have below nginx resource:-

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app2-ingress
  namespace: app2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: web.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app2
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: app2-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

My `app1-service` applied first and it is running fine, now when i applied the second `app2-service` it shows below warning and not able to access it on browser.

```
Annotations:       <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason    Age   From                      Message
  ----     ------    ----  ----                      -------
  Warning  Rejected  54s   nginx-ingress-controller  All hosts are taken by other resources
  Warning  Rejected  54s   nginx-ingress-controller  All hosts are taken by other resources
  Warning  Rejected  54s   nginx-ingress-controller  All hosts are taken by other resources
```

How do i configure my nginx ingress resource to connect multiple service paths on the same hostname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default Nginx Ingress controller doesn't support having different `Ingress` resources with the same hostname. You can have one `Ingress` resource that contains multiple paths, but in this case all apps should live in one namespace. Like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app1-ingress
  namespace: app1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: web.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app1
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: app1-service
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /app2
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: app2-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Splitting ingresses between namespaces is currently not supported by standard Nginx Ingress controller.

You may however take a look at an alternative implementation of [Nginx Ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) by Nginx Inc. They have support for [Mergeable Ingresses](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/main/examples/ingress-resources/mergeable-ingress-types).